# TypeError: must be str, not bytes in Python using nytimes api for data fetching

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I am using nytimesarticle package for scraping in Python 3.6. Whenever I try to search I am getting

> TypeError: must be str, not bytes.

I am running the following code

```
from nytimesarticle import articleAPI
api = articleAPI('apikey')
articles = api.search(q="Obama", 
                      fq={"headline": "Obama", 
                          "source": ["Reuters", 
                                     "AP", 
                                     "The New York Times"]}, 
                      begin_date="20161001", # this can also be an int
                      facet_field=["source", "day_of_week"], 
                      facet_filter=True)
```

and getting the following error

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-1a336947874d> in <module>()
      7                           begin_date="20161001", # this can also be an int
      8                           facet_field=["source", "day_of_week"],
----> 9                           facet_filter=True)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nytimesarticle.py in search(self, response_format, key, **kwargs)
    109 
    110         url = '%s%s?%sapi-key=%s' % (
--> 111             API_ROOT, response_format, self._options(**kwargs), key
    112         )
    113 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nytimesarticle.py in _options(self, **kwargs)
     82         for k, v in kwargs.items():
     83             if k is 'fq' and isinstance(v, dict):
---> 84                 v = _format_fq(v)
     85             elif isinstance(v, list):
     86                 v = ','.join(v)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nytimesarticle.py in _format_fq(d)
     67                     d[k] = ' '.join(map(lambda x: '"' + x + '"', v))
     68                 else:
---> 69                     d[k] = '"' + v + '"'
     70             values = []
     71             for k,v in d.items():

TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: Well this is a bit confusing. At a guess, you have the wrong version downloaded. I can see [`nytimesarticle`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nytimesarticle/0.1.0) which was last updated in 2014 and a new version [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/NYTimesArticleAPInew/1.0.0) that was more-recently updated. It might be a Python 2 / 3 compatibility issue, not sure, since neither lists Python versions on PYPI.

Comment: Given the error and the code that triggers it, it's _very_ probably a Python version issue.